# double power point with extra switch

Tags: workshop

How do I wire a  Deta double power point with extra switch.

I am replacing the double power point and putting in the 
Deta double power point with extra switch.

Thanks in advance

TMac.

[image]

Comment: It looks as though the switch is completely separate from the power outlets. What do you intend for the switch to control? Also, counld you indicate what country you're in?

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box?